# How to slide nav bar from left instead from top?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

Bootstrap supports toggling a navbar from the top. How can I slide it from the left when the screen-size is small?

For example:

[image: preview]

In the screenshot provided above, when the screen is re-sized, the navbar is toggled and slides down from the top. I rather want that the navbar should slide from the left. How can I achieve this function in Bootstrap?

Currently, as per code, the navbar slides from the top. Here is my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-site navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle" type="button"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
            <a href="{% url 'index' %} " class="navbar-brand logo logo-title">
            <span class="logo-icon"><i class="icon icon-search-1 ln-shadow-logo shape-0"></i> </span> <span>Companyname </span> </a> 
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <span>{{user.first_name}}</span> <i class="icon-user fa"></i> <i class=" icon-down-open-big fa"></i></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu user-menu">
                            <li class="active"><a href="account-home.html"><i class="icon-home"></i> Personal Home </a></li>
                            <li><a href="statements.html"><i class=" icon-money "></i> Payment history </a></li>
                            <li><a href="{% url 'logout' %}"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i> Signout </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                {% else %}
                    <li><a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'signup' %}">Signup</a></li>
                {% endif %}
                <li class="postadd"><a class="btn btn-block btn-border btn-post btn-danger" href="{% url 'post_ad' %}">Post Free Add</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 10):

Easy. Change the default behavior from

```
<button ... data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#my-navbar-collapse">
```

to `slide-collapse` functionality which we are going to implement now

```
<button ... data-toggle="slide-collapse" data-target="#my-navbar-collapse">
```

Where the menu is contained within `div` that has the id `my-navbar-collapse`. Note that using id instead of class selector will improve the accessibility because bootstrap will append ARIA states (expanded/collapsed) to the menu
automatically.

```
<div id="my-navbar-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

Class `.collapse` in bootstrap ensures the menu to be initially hidden.

---

**The code:**

And then paste the following Javascript somewhere in the footer:

```
// mobile menu slide from the left
$('[data-toggle="slide-collapse"]').on('click', function() {
    $navMenuCont = $($(this).data('target'));
    $navMenuCont.animate({'width':'toggle'}, 350);
});
```

And the following CSS properties:

```
#my-navbar-collapse {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 280px; /*example + never use min-width with this solution */
    height: 100%;
}
```

Some hints:

- Good idea is also to make responsive query where menu width would be 100% for smartphones instead of always 280px. It works like a charm.
- If you have horizontal menu for desktops, and slider only for smaller devices, you can easily take advantage of [`@grid-float-breakpoint` and `@grid-float-breakpoint-max`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27094073/722036) Bootstrap LESS variables

Comment: this looks simple enough, however, I can't get this to work and there are no errors in the console, so I don't know what is wrong with it.  Do you have example you could post a link to?  Thanks!

Comment: I have implemented this here https://karriere.milchundzucker.de/ . Check out maybe you see what is wrong with your code. Also troubleshooting would be to see if your Javascript is working properly. Make sure to place your Javascript code in the very bottom of the page or ensure to run it on document ready event

Comment: thank you for the example, Hrvoje.  I will check it definitely.  When I couldn't get your solution to work, I  tried for hours doing different things using css3 transform and positioning i.e.: setting the left margin, etc (`width:300px, left:-300px, transform: translateX(300px) or left: 0;, transform: translateX(0)` -- _not in that order, but just different values of these properties_), but I was still not getting the div to slide in from the left. Yes, my javascript is at the bottom of the page, I also have some embedded, so was checking that order as well.

Comment: Great answer. I needed to do some extra stuff besides animate the width when the menu is opened so I instead chose to do `$navMenuCont.toggleClass('open')` so I could handle everything in css by targeting the `.open` class. You could also do transitions in css when the menu is opened.

Answer (score 6):

Try the following and take a look at the following link for more explanation-

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-side navbar-fixed-side-left" role="navigation">
```

Take a look at the following Github link to fix the navbar left or right

[Feature: navbar-fixed-side left or right #13919](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13919)

Another helpful link - [Nav Sidebar With Toggle Button](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/nav-sidebar-with-toggle-button)

Answer (score 6):

Here is the full example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#slide-nav.navbar-inverse').after($('<div class="inverse" id="navbar-height-col"></div>'));
  $('#slide-nav.navbar-default').after($('<div id="navbar-height-col"></div>'));

  var slidewidth = '20%';
  var navbarneg = '-' + slidewidth;

  if ($(window).width() < 767) {
    $('#navbar-height-col').css("width", slidewidth);
    $('#navbar-height-col').css("left", navbarneg);
    $('#slide-nav #slidemenu').css("width", slidewidth);
    $('#slide-nav #slidemenu').css("left", navbarneg);
  }

  $("#slide-nav").on("click", '.navbar-toggle', function(e) {

    // slider is active
    var selected = $(this).hasClass('slide-active');

    // set slidemenu width
    $('#slidemenu').stop().animate({
      left: selected ? navbarneg : '0px'
    });

    // set navbar width
    $('#navbar-height-col').stop().animate({
      left: selected ? navbarneg : '0px'
    });

    // set content let
    $('#page-content').stop().animate({
      left: selected ? '0px' : slidewidth
    });

    // set navbar left
    $('.navbar-header').stop().animate({
      left: selected ? '0px' : slidewidth
    });

    $(this).toggleClass('slide-active', !selected);
    $('#slidemenu').toggleClass('slide-active');

    $('#page-content, .navbar, body, .navbar-header').toggleClass('slide-active');
  });

  var selected = '#slidemenu, #page-content, body, .navbar, .navbar-header';

  $(window).on("resize", function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 767 && $('.navbar-toggle').is(':hidden')) {
      $(selected).removeClass('slide-active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body.slide-active {
  overflow-x: hidden
}
#page-content {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 70px;
  left: 0;
}
#page-content.slide-active {
  padding-top: 0
}
#slide-nav .navbar-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 0;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 17px 0 0 0;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
}
#slide-nav .navbar-toggle.slide-active .icon-bar {
  background: #CC0F0F;
  color: #CC0F0F;
}
.navbar-header {
  position: relative
}
.navbar.navbar-fixed-top.slide-active {
  position: relative
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #slide-nav .container {
    margin: 0!important;
    padding: 0!important;
    height: 100%;
  }
  #slide-nav .navbar-header {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 15px;
  }
  #slide-nav .navbar.slide-active {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
    top: -1px;
    z-index: 1000;
  }
  #slide-nav #slidemenu {
    background: #f7f7f7;
    left: -100%;
    min-width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    top: -8px;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #slide-nav #slidemenu .navbar-nav {
    min-width: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #slide-nav #slidemenu .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu li a {
    min-width: 0;
    width: 80%;
    white-space: normal;
  }
  #slide-nav {
    border-top: 0
  }
  #slide-nav.navbar-inverse #slidemenu {
    background: #333
  }
  #navbar-height-col {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #f7f7f7;
  }
  #navbar-height-col.inverse {
    background: #333;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 0;
  }
  #slide-nav .navbar-form {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 8px 0;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*fast clearfixer*/
  }
  #slide-nav .navbar-form .form-control {
    text-align: center
  }
  #slide-nav .navbar-form .btn {
    width: 100%
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #page-content {
    left: 0!important
  }
  .navbar.navbar-fixed-top.slide-active {
    position: fixed
  }
  .navbar-header {
    left: 0!important
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="slide-nav">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-toggle">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="slidemenu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Menu</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu</a>
        </li>

      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="page-content">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="no-margin-top">Left Sidebar menu</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid sunt minus libero quas soluta blanditiis voluptatibus, eveniet sint tempora! Maxime!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad laudantium deleniti ratione ea voluptas, dolore expedita nisi? Veniam, doloremque, reiciendis.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci blanditiis nam esse molestiae voluptatem maiores fugiat nulla commodi magni impedit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora ducimus iure ipsa ea officia aliquid quibusdam nostrum obcaecati itaque temporibus!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid sunt minus libero quas soluta blanditiis voluptatibus, eveniet sint tempora! Maxime!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad laudantium deleniti ratione ea voluptas, dolore expedita nisi? Veniam, doloremque, reiciendis.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci blanditiis nam esse molestiae voluptatem maiores fugiat nulla commodi magni impedit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora ducimus iure ipsa ea officia aliquid quibusdam nostrum obcaecati itaque temporibus!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid sunt minus libero quas soluta blanditiis voluptatibus, eveniet sint tempora! Maxime!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad laudantium deleniti ratione ea voluptas, dolore expedita nisi? Veniam, doloremque, reiciendis.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci blanditiis nam esse molestiae voluptatem maiores fugiat nulla commodi magni impedit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora ducimus iure ipsa ea officia aliquid quibusdam nostrum obcaecati itaque temporibus!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid sunt minus libero quas soluta blanditiis voluptatibus, eveniet sint tempora! Maxime!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad laudantium deleniti ratione ea voluptas, dolore expedita nisi? Veniam, doloremque, reiciendis.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci blanditiis nam esse molestiae voluptatem maiores fugiat nulla commodi magni impedit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora ducimus iure ipsa ea officia aliquid quibusdam nostrum obcaecati itaque temporibus!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Without Plugin, We can do this**

See The LINK

**[Bootstrap multi-level responsive menu with left side slide toggle for mobile devices](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/xrK79)**

```js
$('[data-toggle="slide-collapse"]').on('click', function() {
  $navMenuCont = $($(this).data('target'));
  $navMenuCont.animate({
    'width': 'toggle'
  }, 350);
  $(".menu-overlay").fadeIn(500);
});

$(".menu-overlay").click(function(event) {
  $(".navbar-toggle").trigger("click");
  $(".menu-overlay").fadeOut(500);
});

// if ($(window).width() >= 767) {
//     $('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
//         $(this).find('>.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
//     }, function() {
//         $(this).find('>.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
//     });

//     $('ul.nav li.dropdown-submenu').hover(function() {
//         $(this).find('>.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
//     }, function() {
//         $(this).find('>.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
//     });


//     $('ul.dropdown-menu [data-toggle=dropdown]').on('click', function(event) {
//         event.preventDefault();
//         event.stopPropagation();
//         $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('open');
//         $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
//         $('b', this).toggleClass("caret caret-up");
//     });
// }

// $(window).resize(function() {
//     if( $(this).width() >= 767) {
//         $('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
//             $(this).find('>.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
//         }, function() {
//             $(this).find('>.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
//         });
//     }
// });

var windowWidth = $(window).width();
if (windowWidth > 767) {
  // $('ul.dropdown-menu [data-toggle=dropdown]').on('click', function(event) {
  //     event.preventDefault();
  //     event.stopPropagation();
  //     $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('open');
  //     $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
  //     $('b', this).toggleClass("caret caret-up");
  // });

  $('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('>.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
  }, function() {
    $(this).find('>.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
  });

  $('ul.nav li.dropdown-submenu').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('>.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
  }, function() {
    $(this).find('>.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
  });


  $('ul.dropdown-menu [data-toggle=dropdown]').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('open');
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
    // $('b', this).toggleClass("caret caret-up");
  });
}
if (windowWidth < 767) {
  $('ul.dropdown-menu [data-toggle=dropdown]').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('open');
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
    // $('b', this).toggleClass("caret caret-up");
  });
}

// $('.dropdown a').append('Some text');
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #slide-navbar-collapse {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 15px;
    z-index: 999999;
    width: 280px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    overflow: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    max-height: inherit;
  }
  .menu-overlay {
    display: none;
    background-color: #000;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    /* IE7 & 8 */
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 49;
  }
  .navbar-fixed-top {
    position: initial !important;
  }
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }
  ul.nav.navbar-nav li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  }
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header,
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 15px;
  }
}

.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

li.dropdown a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

li.dropdown>a:before {
  content: "\f107";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

li.dropdown-submenu>a:before {
  content: "\f107";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

ul.dropdown-menu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: none !important;
}

li.dropdown.open {
  border-bottom: 0px !important;
}

li.dropdown-submenu.open {
  border-bottom: 0px !important;
}

li.dropdown-submenu>a {
  font-weight: bold !important;
}

li.dropdown>a {
  font-weight: bold !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  font-weight: bold !important;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 15px;
}

li.dropdown>a:before {
  content: "\f107";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: 9px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 767px) {
  li.dropdown-submenu>a {
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 15px;
  }
  li.dropdown>a:before {
    content: "\f107";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    position: absolute;
    right: 3px;
    top: 12px;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="slide-collapse" data-target="#slide-navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="slide-navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                  <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">SubMenu 1</span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                      <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">SubMenu 2</span></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
    <div class="menu-overlay"></div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1>Resize the window to see the result</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus non bibendum sem, et sodales massa. Proin quis velit vel nisl imperdiet rhoncus vitae id tortor. Praesent blandit tellus in enim sollicitudin rutrum. Integer ullamcorper, augue ut tristique
        ultrices, augue magna placerat ex, ac varius mauris ante sed dui. Fusce ullamcorper vulputate magna, a malesuada nunc pellentesque sit amet. Donec posuere placerat erat, sed ornare enim aliquam vitae. Nullam pellentesque auctor augue, vel commodo
        dolor porta ac. Sed libero eros, fringilla ac lorem in, blandit scelerisque lorem. Suspendisse iaculis justo velit, sit amet fringilla velit ornare a. Sed consectetur quam eget ipsum luctus bibendum. Ut nisi lectus, viverra vitae ipsum sit amet,
        condimentum condimentum neque. In maximus suscipit eros ut eleifend. Donec venenatis mauris nulla, ac bibendum metus bibendum vel.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus non bibendum sem, et sodales massa. Proin quis velit vel nisl imperdiet rhoncus vitae id tortor. Praesent blandit tellus in enim sollicitudin rutrum. Integer ullamcorper, augue ut tristique
        ultrices, augue magna placerat ex, ac varius mauris ante sed dui. Fusce ullamcorper vulputate magna, a malesuada nunc pellentesque sit amet. Donec posuere placerat erat, sed ornare enim aliquam vitae. Nullam pellentesque auctor augue, vel commodo
        dolor porta ac. Sed libero eros, fringilla ac lorem in, blandit scelerisque lorem. Suspendisse iaculis justo velit, sit amet fringilla velit ornare a. Sed consectetur quam eget ipsum luctus bibendum. Ut nisi lectus, viverra vitae ipsum sit amet,
        condimentum condimentum neque. In maximus suscipit eros ut eleifend. Donec venenatis mauris nulla, ac bibendum metus bibendum vel.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus non bibendum sem, et sodales massa. Proin quis velit vel nisl imperdiet rhoncus vitae id tortor. Praesent blandit tellus in enim sollicitudin rutrum. Integer ullamcorper, augue ut tristique
        ultrices, augue magna placerat ex, ac varius mauris ante sed dui. Fusce ullamcorper vulputate magna, a malesuada nunc pellentesque sit amet. Donec posuere placerat erat, sed ornare enim aliquam vitae. Nullam pellentesque auctor augue, vel commodo
        dolor porta ac. Sed libero eros, fringilla ac lorem in, blandit scelerisque lorem. Suspendisse iaculis justo velit, sit amet fringilla velit ornare a. Sed consectetur quam eget ipsum luctus bibendum. Ut nisi lectus, viverra vitae ipsum sit amet,
        condimentum condimentum neque. In maximus suscipit eros ut eleifend. Donec venenatis mauris nulla, ac bibendum metus bibendum vel.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus non bibendum sem, et sodales massa. Proin quis velit vel nisl imperdiet rhoncus vitae id tortor. Praesent blandit tellus in enim sollicitudin rutrum. Integer ullamcorper, augue ut tristique
        ultrices, augue magna placerat ex, ac varius mauris ante sed dui. Fusce ullamcorper vulputate magna, a malesuada nunc pellentesque sit amet. Donec posuere placerat erat, sed ornare enim aliquam vitae. Nullam pellentesque auctor augue, vel commodo
        dolor porta ac. Sed libero eros, fringilla ac lorem in, blandit scelerisque lorem. Suspendisse iaculis justo velit, sit amet fringilla velit ornare a. Sed consectetur quam eget ipsum luctus bibendum. Ut nisi lectus, viverra vitae ipsum sit amet,
        condimentum condimentum neque. In maximus suscipit eros ut eleifend. Donec venenatis mauris nulla, ac bibendum metus bibendum vel.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus non bibendum sem, et sodales massa. Proin quis velit vel nisl imperdiet rhoncus vitae id tortor. Praesent blandit tellus in enim sollicitudin rutrum. Integer ullamcorper, augue ut tristique
        ultrices, augue magna placerat ex, ac varius mauris ante sed dui. Fusce ullamcorper vulputate magna, a malesuada nunc pellentesque sit amet. Donec posuere placerat erat, sed ornare enim aliquam vitae. Nullam pellentesque auctor augue, vel commodo
        dolor porta ac. Sed libero eros, fringilla ac lorem in, blandit scelerisque lorem. Suspendisse iaculis justo velit, sit amet fringilla velit ornare a. Sed consectetur quam eget ipsum luctus bibendum. Ut nisi lectus, viverra vitae ipsum sit amet,
        condimentum condimentum neque. In maximus suscipit eros ut eleifend. Donec venenatis mauris nulla, ac bibendum metus bibendum vel.
      </p>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Bootstrap 4 (update 2020)**

IMO the simplest way is to override the Bootstrap collapse animation so that it transitions from left to right (width instead of height). Instead of toggling `display:block` when `.collapse.show` is used, the Navbar is always `display:block` which enables you to position as needed and use transitions from both collapsing directions...

Open menu: `.collapse` - `.collapsing` - `.collapse.show`
Close menu: `.collapse.show` - `.collapsing.show` - `.collapse`

```
    .navbar-collapse {
        position: absolute;
        top: 54px;
        left: -100%;
        width: 100%;
        transition: all 0.4s ease;
        display: block;
        opacity: 0.8;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapsing {
        height: auto !important;
        left: -100%;
        margin-left: 1px;
        transition: all 0.2s ease;
        opacity: 0.9;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.show {
        margin-left: 100%;
        transition: all 0.2s ease;
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

https://codeply.com/go/KSS4pjqtJy (full width)
https://codeply.com/p/BvPCPA1wgZ (full height)

Answer (score 1):

Use this for right-to-left sliding:

HTML :

```
<div class="nav ">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
       </ul>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav{
    position: fixed;
    right:0;
    top: 70px;
    width: 250px;
    height: calc(100vh - 70px);
    background-color: #333;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;

}
.nav-view{
    transform: translateX(0);
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a#click-a').click(function(){
    $('.nav').toggleClass('nav-view');
  });
});
```

Download source files: http://www.themeswild.com/read/slide-navigation-left-to-right

Comment: DOES YOUR ANSWER HAVE TO BE IN ALL CAPS?

Comment: :) , hey its just for highlighting purpose .

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question here: [Bootstrap 3 Slide in Menu / Navbar on Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20863288/bootstrap-3-slide-in-menu-navbar-on-mobile) where the accepted answer is to use jasny bootstrap.  There are other answers there though if Jasny wasn't your cup of tea.

Answer (score 0):

#### Please refer this [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/appsparkler/pen/ypgaRL?editors=1111).  The following important points to note:

- [Animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css) library required. Specifically the `slideInLeft` and the `slideOutLeft` animations.
- Work with [dropdown](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/) instead of the [collapse](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/) component of Bootstrap.
- Set the `dropdown-menu` element `static` by applying the class `position-static` on it.
- *Leverage* the `show` class that is applied on the `dropdown` element when the `dropdown-menu` is shown.
- *Leverage* `left` CSS property to carry out the transition.  Basically, we'll set `left:-100%` on `.dropdown.show .dropdown-menu` and we'll set `left:0px` on `.dropdown .dropdown-menu`

#### Screenshot:

[image]

**NOTE** : You can tryout other animations for the `dropdown-menu` from **animate.css**.

Good Luck...