# How to change transition animation in Navbar using bootstrap?

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I am using bootstrap navbar and it drop down animation on mobile screen. 
Example : http://www.bootply.com/render/tS4enOrpeF

Right now the animation of the list is like top down.

Is there any way to change it to right to left. 
Something like this : http://html5up.net/spectral

Answer (score 0):

This of course has nothing to do with WordPress, but with CSS.

There are equal questions, have a look here: [Bootstrap - How to slide nav bar from left instead from top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31641352/bootstrap-how-to-slide-nav-bar-from-left-instead-from-top)