# Bootstrap 4 - how to change collapse direction of nav?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

By default in Bootstrap 4 nanbar collapse direction is 'from top to bottom'. I want to change it to 'from right to left'. How can I do this? You can see my code below:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        <i class="fa fa-times close" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav flex-row-reverse">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43930068/bootstrap-4-mobile-nav-bar-slide-from-left/43936913

Answer (score 2):

Need to remove **flex-row-reverse** from below ul & add below css

```
 <ul class="navbar-nav flex-row-reverse">
```

```css
 
    .navbar-collapse {
        position: absolute;
        top: 54px;
        left: 100%;
        padding-left: 15px;
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
        width: 100%;
        transition: all 0.4s ease;
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapsing {
        height: auto !important;
        margin-left: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transition: all 0.2s ease;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.show {
        left: 0;
    }
```

```html
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        <i class="fa fa-times close" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```